# Angular "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript

Before I start my question, I'd like to let you know that I already did a big research, and I cannot find a solution ( explanation ) why I get this error.

Please also note, that I am totally new on Angular, and I just started to learn how it works.

So, the problem I have is what I have entered in the title of this question.

What I try to do, is to build a login system using the Firebase, based on a course I purchase on Udemy.

The code I use is the following:

**auth.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable ()
export class AuthService {
    token: string;

    // ...

    singInUser ( email: string, password: string ) {
        // login process here ...
    }

    // Responsible to retrieve the authenticated user token
    getToken () {   
        return firebase
            .auth ()
            .currentUser
            .getIdToken ();
    }
}
```

**data-storage.service.ts**

```
// ... Dependencies here
@Injectable ()
export class DataStorageService {
    private recipeEndPoint: string = 'https://my-unique-id.firebaseio.com/recipes.json';
    private recipeSubscription: Observable<any> = new Observable();

    constructor ( private http: Http,
                  private recipes: RecipeService,
                  private authService: AuthService ) {}

    // other functionality ...

    getRecipes () {
        const token = this.authService.getToken ();

        token.then (
            ( token: string ) => {
                this.recipeSubscription = this.http.get ( this.recipeEndPoint + '?auth=' + token ).map (
                    ( data: Response ) => {
                        return data.json ();
                    }
                );

                // THIS PARTICULAR CODE WORKS AS EXPECTED
                // WITH NO ISSUES
                this.recipeSubscription.subscribe (
                    ( data: Response ) => {
                        console.log ( 'Data response: ', data );
                    },
                    ( error ) => {
                        console.log ( 'Error: ' + error );
                    }
                )
            }
        );

        // This is supposed to return an Observable to the caller
        return this.recipeSubscription;
    }
}
```

**header.component.ts**

```
// Dependencies here ...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dataStorage: DataStorageService, private recipeService: RecipeService) { }

  // Other Code Here ...

  onFetchData() {
    let recipeSubscription = this.dataStorage.getRecipes();

    // THIS RETURNS TRUE
    console.log(recipeSubscription instanceof Observable);

    // THIS LINE THEN RETURNS THE MESSAGE:
    // ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    recipeSubscription.subscribe();

    // IF I COMMENT OUT THE PREVIOUS LINE
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        // THIS RETURNS TRUE
        console.log(recipeSubscription instanceof Observable);
      },
      500
    );

    setTimeout(
      () => {
        // AS WELL THIS ONE RETURNS TRUE
        console.log(recipeSubscription instanceof Observable);
      },
      1000
    );

    setTimeout(
      () => {
        // AS WELL THIS ONE RETURNS TRUE
        console.log(recipeSubscription instanceof Observable);
      },
      1500
    );
  }
}
```

So, unfortunately, I cannot see what could be wrong with this code. Can anyone spot anything I did wrong?

**Note:** *I have removed parts of my code just for make the snippets more readable. If you need any other part, please feel free to ask me, and I will provide it here.*

UPDATE #1

This is how it looks like the `header.component.html`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">Logo Here</div>

        <div class="navbar-default">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!-- Left Navigation Options -->
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <!-- Right Navigation Options -->
                <li class="dropdown" appDropdown>
                    <a routerLink="/" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="onSaveData()">Save Data</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <!-- Here is where I call the onFetchData method -->
                            <a style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="onFetchData()">Fetch Data</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: from where do you call the `onFetchData()` method in your `header.component.ts` ?

Comment: In data-storage servcie you have already subscribed.

Comment: The `onFetchData()` it is called from the component HTML using the code `(click)="onFetchData()"`

Comment: It is probably problem because on that same observable you are subscribing two times.

Comment: @AdamA then I could subscribe only once per `Observable`?

Comment: @AdamA let me check it out :)

Comment: @AdamA it seems like this is not the problem. I have commented out the first subscription in the `data-storage.service.ts`, and then in the `header.component.ts` I get again the same error in the first `subscribe` call. :(

Comment: Probably problem is in other place but in the best of my knowledge using subscribe more than once is wrong

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue seems to be the order in which your code gets executed, more specifically the `getRecipes()` method :

```js
// Numbers indicate the execution order

getRecipes () {
    const token = this.authService.getToken ();

    // 1. You call a promise, which will take a while to execute...
    token.then (
        ( token: string ) => {
            // 3. Finally, this bit gets executed, but only when the promise resolves.
            this.recipeSubscription = ...
        }
    );

    // 2. Then, you return a variable that hasn't been assigned yet,
    // due to the async nature of the promise.
    return this.recipeSubscription;
}
```

The solution to this is that your `getRecipes ()` method SHOULD NOT SUBSCRIBE. It should **return either a Promise or an Observable**.

Something like this:

```js
getRecipes() {
    // Convert the initial promise into an observable
    // so can you use operators like map(), mergeMap()... to transform it.
    const tokenObs = Observable.fromPromise(this.authService.getToken());

    // Merge the token observable into an HTTP observable
    // and return the JSON data from the response.
    return tokenObs
      .mergeMap(token => this.http.get('XXX?auth=' + token))
      .map(resp => resp.json());
}
```

Then, the calling code in `HeaderComponent` becomes :

```js
const recipeObs = this.dataStorage.getRecipes();
recipesObs.subcribe(jsonData => {
  // Use the JSON data from the HTTP response
});
```

Several remarks:

- You need to explicitly import the RxJS operators used in your code. If you follow my example, you need to add the following imports at the beginning:

```js
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
```

- You should NEVER subscribe in the method that creates the observable. In your case, don't subscribe in `getRecipes()`. ALWAYS subscribe at the last minute possible. You can subscribe multiple times to the same observable, but be aware that each subscription re-executes the observable (in the case of an http request, it means you run the request multiple times; not ideal...).
- It is not a good idea to call your variable `recipeSubscription` since it contains an `Observable`, not a `Subscription`. A subscription is what `subscribe()` returns. In other words: `const subscription = observable.subscribe()`.
- I see that you're using the Firebase SDK directly. Are you aware of [AngularFire library](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure I have understood. What I try in the `getRecipes()` method is to first get the token returned by firebase library checks, and once I have it, I'd like to send a request to Firebase in order to load my recipes. Finally, once I have the recipes, I'd like to return them to the caller, so the caller can do whatever it needs to. I can see that is too complicated the login in the `getRecipes()` but also, I don't have a clue on how to do so :(

Comment: By the way @AngularFrance, I appreciate your help so far :)

Comment: I have updated my answer with a full code sample to illustrate.

Comment: Just awesome !! :) ;) Thank you :)

Answer (score 35):

I got the same error from using an unitialized EventEmitter:

```
@Output() change: EventEmitter<any>;
```

instead of:

```
@Output() change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

The error occurred in the higher-level component that tried to subscribe to the change event.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is, you're returning an observable and re-assigning it in the response of Token().

Try making a Subject of the Observable you have now, i find these easier to use.

```
public recipeSubscription: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

Change your assignment from

```
this.recipeSubscription = this.http.get....
```

To

```
let response = this.http.get....
```

Subscribe on that within the function this gets called:

```
response.subscribe((res) => {this.recipeSubscription.next(res)})
```

Now you can subscribe directly on the property

```
this.dataStorage.recipeSubscription.subscribe((res) => {
    // Do stuff.
});

this.dataStorage.getRecipes();
```

I hope this is enough to help you :)

Answer (score 6):

**Problem**

I stumble upon the same error and the reason was that I was initializing my `@Output` event emitter inside ngOnInit().

```
export class MyClass implements OnInit {

    @Output()
    onChange : EventEmitter<void>;

    ngOnInit() {
        // DO NOT initialize @Output event here
        this.onChange = new EventEmitter<void>();    
    }
}
```

**Solution**

When I changed the initialization to the same place of the declaration it worked.

```
export class MyClass implements OnInit {

    @Output()
    onChange : EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

I think this happens because the parent component tries to subscribe to the event too soon (before `ngOnInit()` is triggered).

Answer (score 0):

**Ionic 4.**

I had a method that subscribes to an observable, calling that method within `ngOnInit`, raised this error. Moving the method call to constructor solved my problem.

Comment: I Have Changed it to Constructor but still dosentwork

Answer (score 0):

As other answers already mentioned you should return observable in order to subscribe it.
In my case it was throwing error despite that. I just restarted my angular app with

```
ng serve
```

and then it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

**I am using angular8**,
Had similar challenge.
I was supposed to hit an endpoint with some valid credentials appended to my get/post, thus calling the methods before checking the credentials caused the problem.

Making sure that you're authenticated before any action should solve the problem:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.isAuthenticated().then(status => {
      if (status === true) {
      this.getClients();
      this.getCities();
     } else {
    this.routerCtrl.navigate(["login"]);
   }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that same error where it was subscribing to an undefined value, so what I did was use an if statement to check that there's actually a value to subscribe to. Like so:

```
if(this.memberService.getSetMember() !== undefined) {
    this.memberService.getSetMember().subscribe((value: any) => this.member = value)                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by binding the observable value to the subject.

```
observable = behaviourSubject.asObservable();
```

I added this in the constructor.

Below is the skelton of the code.

```
  subjectVar: BehaviorSubject<type> = new BehaviorSubject<type>({} as type)
  observableVar: Observable<type>

  constructor(){
     this.observableVar = this.subjectVar.asObservable();
  }
  
  pulic function()Observable<type>{
      foo();
      return observableVar

  }

  foo(){
     let var = someValue
     subjectVar.next(var)
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I just had a `switch` with a misspelling, and some code was just not executed. As soon as I fixed the misspelling, the error was gone